# How to disable certificate transparency check in macOS Mojave(10.14)

Tags: macos, network, wifi, mojave, certificate

In macOS Mojave, [certificate transparency](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205280) check is enabled. Because the OS terminates all TLS connections that doesn’t use transparent certificates, [macOS Mojave cannot connect to WPA2 Enterprise corporate networks](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8566745). Is there any solution to turn off certificate transparency check for one special certificate or for all certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificate Transparency only applies to publicly trusted certificates, which mean WPA2 certs aren’t affected by CT.
It’s probably because the certificate was signed with MD5, which [isn’t trusted, starting from iOS 12 and macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209028).

The reason why MD5-signed certs aren’t trusted is because [MD5 weaknesses allow fake TLS certs to be created](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-md5-weakness-allows-fake-ssl-certificates-to-be-created.html).

There is simply no such way to make macOS Mojave to make trust MD5 certs; request the network administrator to update & resign the cert with a different algorithm.